# I am unable to ask a question on Stack Overflow due to reaching the question limit

Tags: support, post-ban

I am unable to ask a question from my Stack Overflow account. It shows the below error:

> You have reached your question limit. Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

[image: The message I see when I try to ask a question]

How can I get this access back?

Comment: Note the part about deleted questions, which count against you.

Comment: Re-opening so I can answer the user's specific issue since they came here for support; will close as duplicate after.  Since they need a moderator to show them where their deleted questions are; I'll do that in my answer. The irony of closing this as a duplicate when the duplicate *specifically* asks people to ask a question on meta for their deleted posts is not lost on me.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker alternatively you could have edited this question to be specific (and linking to the duplicate) like "according to {link} I need to ask separate q to get list of old deleted questions. I currently see X questions and have only positive scores" so you don't need to trigger "those gold-badge/diamond @#$@ answer questions to get the rep and then close post to block anyone else to get their point"...

Comment: @alexeiLevenkov we don’t expect the OP to know that, we do expect people voting to close to have read the post they claim this is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 8 deleted questions that it looks like you deleted. Deleted questions -- even self deleted questions -- count against you asking new questions when they're negatively scored.  Your best bet is to clean up these questions and flag them for undeletion.

You can clean up these questions by:

- editing them so they have proper punctuation and capitalization
- Scoping your question to a problem you're facing; or something lots of programmers will face

I'll go through one of your negatively scored questions and edit it to show you what that'd look like, and include it here.

#### Deleted Questions

- [How to Save Array of object in UserDefaults in iOS 12.0. using Any Array [[String: Any]]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54123466/how-to-save-array-of-object-in-userdefaults-in-ios-12-0-using-any-array-strin)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54684505/objective-c-amazon-and-xctest-framework-not-found-how-to-solve-this
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682392/videos-rotate-issue
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188527/how-to-update-model-versioning-in-core-data-model-for-new-release-when-previous
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51380744/what-importance-of-codable-in-swift
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51707662/webview-deprecated-show-in-xcode-9-4
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52337919/how-to-access-iphone-xs-max-iphone-xs-iphone-xr
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191335/how-to-make-video-using-multiple-images-video-with-different-audio-with-diff

Since you're not blocked from answering, I won't include the links to your deleted answers.

Edit: I cleaned up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682392/videos-rotate-issue).  I don't know if it meets your original intent or if it makes sense in the space (I am not a native iOS developer), but have a look and see that as an example of what I'm talking about.

- The title was expanded on to be sure that people who search a search engine will have something to find
- The capitalization and grammatical issues were addressed

Comment: Thank you George. I will try to clean this up as soon as possible

Comment: I have one question related to undeleting. I might not have all the information related to the deleted questions so how to handle those? For eg. I might not have the code for all of them now

Comment: @SAXENA_RAHUL That's a good question: Keep in mind that you don't need to fix all of the questions; just some of them; and that in some cases, having the code is not necessary (unless it's a troubleshooting issue on your own code).

Comment: While I'm not one to comment on votes, I would love to know what anybody has to object to this answer.

Comment: @yivi it's me. They object to me. They object to me helping someone when the listed duplicate specifically says that's what they're supposed to do and that's exactly what we're supposed to do as moderators.

Comment: @yivi up till today the consensus seemed to be that we closed against the dupe and sometimes a mod came by and dropped the links to the deleted posts in a comment. It looks like the moderators rather try to give a bit more tailored guidance and not all of the 0,015% users adjusted to that new state-of-mind or think this is useful at all.

Comment: To be honest that linked question didn't cleared anything to me. Also I only see 1 deleted question in my account, so this answer is definitely helpful

Comment: FYI, George, I am one who objects some of your recent actions and some of your take on community policing; but I have nothing against you personally and I dislike user targeting. I'm just commenting to try to hopefully push some users to reflect that we shouldn't allow our emotions run wild, and still **vote on the content, not the person**. And to give you some support nonetheless. I may disagree with you, strongly in some points, but we still should act like reasonable human beings. Whatever that is. And with that I'm off. Peace!

Comment: @SAXENA_RAHUL if you would had only a comment with links to your deleted questions, would that have been enough?

Comment: *To be honest that linked question didn't cleared anything to me* we would love to hear @SAXENA_RAHUL how we can make that better.

Comment: A much precise and short version is what would have been better

Comment: Hmmm, that will be a challenge @SAXENA_RAHUL ... that content doesn't easily translate in a couple of tweets ;) ... we have a lot to tell you  ... anyway. I'll see if I can find some users who would be able to make a precise and short version as well. Thanks for your feedback, appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a TL;DR version stating solution to lift the ban.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I have edited and undeleted those, which I think can be useful to others. Now when will the ban be lifted ?

Comment: It already has been lifted. Thanks for your help again regardless of all the heat your action has generated

Comment: @saxena_rahul you’re welcome, and that’s the job.

Comment: I'm not too hot on the downvotes on this. Yes, there's a duplicate, but george clearly put the extra mile in for this user. While we can't guarantee someone will be able to for every user, why downvote it when someone takes the time? Feels backwards. The advice here is clearly appropriately tailored to the user in question to have value beyond what the duplicate already offers.

Comment: @Magisch well to me voting on this was mainly driven by the fact that only moderators can do such answers - because it involves analyzing a list of deleted questions which is available only to moderators. Voting up would mean I encourage spending moderator efforts like that and down would mean that I am against this. I believe this is important and recommend other voters to take this into account

Comment: ...^^^ it is important to note that answering like that is not the only way out here (otherwise I would just vote up and be done with it). Other way would be as mentioned by @rene above - moderator just comments with a list of links and OP takes it from there - and in case if they need they can further ask about specific questions from that list. Further analysing questions in cases like that would be very different in that it wouldn't need moderator involvement at all - when there is a link, all details can be provided by asker or by 10K readers

Comment: @gnat: I think George is free to spend his time the way he pleases. Using your vote to influence his activities seems, um, what's the nice way to say manipulative? Also, this line of reasoning treads awfully close to voting on the author not the content.

Comment: @JonEricson I think I can vote as I please. And I am not interested in his activities (nor I think I can even influence that, no matter if I vote up or down). I only use my vote to help other see whether I support moderators doing like that or not

Comment: @gnat: You know [these guidelines apply on meta too](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed). But that's beside the point. Voting because you want to control (or at least influence) the way others behave regardless of the content is unethical. Or is that another way [we've become like Facebook](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2014/06/everything-we-know-about-facebooks-secret-mood-manipulation-experiment/373648/)?

Comment: @JonEricson good catch, I meant to write "I can vote as I please _as long as it's not personal_". As for the influencing, this is unavoidable effect of voting that rates content. Votes are intended to tell readers whether content is good or bad and this is by design an attempt to influence their behavior with regards to rated posts...

Comment: ...Your reference to article about Facebook suggests that you are primarily concerned that this influence can get manipulative, well yes I worry about this too. I can't make others vote fairly but I try to do that myself and what helps me here is making a rational explanation prior to voting in a particular direction. Usually I keep these explanations by myself but since other user expressed their concerns about voting here I decided to share my reasoning